# How to get a value from JSON string in Swift using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have a `JSON` string and would like to obtain some values from it. I am using `SwiftyJSON` to extract some values from the JSON string. But not sure why I am getting empty values from it. How can I retrieve all the values such as `version, ephemeralPublicKey, transactionId` etc from this JSON string using `SwiftyJSON`?

**Code:**

```
let decryptedPaymentData:NSString! = NSString(data: encryptedPaymentData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print("decryptedPaymentData = \(decryptedPaymentData)")  

//extract values here  
let decryptedJsonStr = JSON(decryptedPaymentData)
let version = decryptedJsonStr["version"].stringValue
print("version = \(version)")
```

**Output:**

```
    decryptedPaymentData = {"version":"EC_v1",
        "header":{
        "ephemeralPublicKey":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE1AhSWKm/KoXMmRU/dm825c8M3HZUYH/X8SH2zvzLgF9AN0ifWNH6KMLdRXhYSbnhVv0eDz+cJhf0I6o3oSc1bg==","publicKeyHash":"y9Gi+xcoSJjzegmkLQJ1KB7oehqavQom5EDwNCv+nHE=","transactionId":"7f83d3eff0de5d1313b6689d274d29dd7f71fe3763829f488ff4ac23a3dd40c5"}
        }

version =
```

**Solution with Output:**

```
let decryptedJsonStr = JSON.parse(decryptedPaymentData as String)
let version = decryptedJsonStr["version"].stringValue
let epk = decryptedJsonStr["header"]["ephemeralPublicKey"].stringValue
print("version = \(version)")
print("epk = \(epk)")

version = EC_v1
epk=MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEoyXCcna7anfdPXVJcRFF6+SOgCgCqRqcdx/p0YrTy3nUU1LQ977EwuddRvnHKi5WemLnWIf3AzPDGLMY1L2Pog==
```

Comment: If this hadn't helped http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/10/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-2/, please post and output, at least from print() function, what you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON(decryptedPaymentData)` just constructs a JSON object which is a string `"{\"version\":...}"`.

To parse it, you need to use the `parse()` function:

```
let decryptedJsonStr = JSON.parse(decryptedPaymentData)
//                          ^^^^^
```

Note that you don't need to convert the NSData into NSString yourself, as you could use the `init(data:options:error:)` constructor:

```
let decryptedJsonStr = JSON(data: encryptedPaymentData)
//                          ^^^^^
```

Comment: Ok, but then how can I get something like the `ephemeralPublicKey` which is embedded within `header` key ?

Comment: @user2325154 `decryptedJsonStr["header"]["ephemeralPublicKey"].stringValue`

Comment: Perfect ! That worked! Thanks a lot for your solution. I have updated my original post with the solution.

Comment: @user2325154 If this works please [click the ✓ next to this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks.